# Convert CTL* formula to CTL

Tags: logic, computation-tree-logic

I have a CTL* formula: $\mathsf{EF}[p\land \mathsf{AX}[q\ \mathsf{U}\ r]]$ but in my application, I am limited to CTL. To my understanding, this formula is no valid CTL and I wonder whether I can transform it (preserving semantic, of course). The CTL* formula should express "there exists a path on which $p$ holds and from that point, in all subsequent states, $q$ holds until $r$ eventually holds".

Is this correct and is there a way to convert it to CTL?

Comment: Welcome to cstheory, a Q&A site for *research-level* questions in *theoretical computer science* (TCS). Your question does not appear to be a research-level question in TCS. Please see the [FAQ] for more information on what is meant by this. Your question might be suitable for [cs.se] which has a broader scope.

Comment: Migrating to [CS.SE].

Comment: Why do you say that formula is not a CTL formula?  What is your CTL language definition (BNF)?

Answer (score 2):

A somewhat late response:

The formula $AX(p U q)$ is equivalent to the CTL formula $AXA(pUq)$: Consider a state that satisfies the former, then in all the paths from it, after one transition it holds that $pUq$. Thus, in all the paths after one transition, we reach a state from which all the paths satisfy $p U q$, so the state satisfies the latter. The converse is obvious, sine the second formula is harder to satisfy.

So an equivalent CTL formula is 
$EF[p\wedge AXA(pUq)]$.